# Video drivers for VAIO on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

So, ive just installed Windows 7 on my Sony VAIO vgn-sz5xn.

Problem is that I cant find drivers for my graphics card - NVIDIA GeForce Go 7400 GPU

Tried latest driver found on 
http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_win7_64bit_179.48_beta.html

The following notebooks are not supported in this release:
Sony VAIO notebooks (please contact the notebook OEM for driver support for these notebooks)

I checked at VAIO sites, but havent found anything about drivers for Windows 7.

Tried installing Vista drivers, but they complain that its wrong OS blablah.

o_O

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of googling i found the answer.

Download the latest drivers from this page: http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/drivers

Be sure to get the modified INF file.

Comment: Then follow this tutorial for updating drivers in Win7.
http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/11997-have-disk-method-for-windows-7-vista/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to download [modified drivers](http://downloads.guru3d.com/Videocards---NVIDIA-GeForce-Windows-7_c37.html), but I've never tried this on nvidia and on windows 7 OS (only windows XP / ATI card with DHModTools). So **I can't guarantee anything**, and it's only your responsability (it's possible that you can't boot anymore, or just in "safe mode"). But if you have nothing important on your computer and know how to restore the factory configuration (or format the computer), go for it!