# nVidia driver is not installed for x64 Windows 7 (Vaio VGN-SZ460N)

Tags: 64-bit, graphics-card, sony-vaio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video drivers for VAIO on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/98394/video-drivers-for-vaio-on-windows-7)

I just upgraded memory to 4GB for Sony Vaio VGN-SZ460N laptop and trying to install Windows 7 x64.

All works fine with default drivers, except video - I am not able to set resolution more than 1024x768.

[Technical specification](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&partNumber=VGNSZ460N/C#specifications) says that this model is using:
Chipset : Intel® 945GM
Processor : NVIDIA® GeForce® Go 7400 notebook graphics processing unit (GPU) and Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 950

I was trying to use Intel 945GM driver, for Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and get error:

> This computer does not meet the mininum requirements for installing
>   the software

Also, I was trying to download nVidia GeForce Go 7400 x64 but it says that there is no compatible hardware. Actually, it has disclaimer that those drivers doesn't work for Sony vaio and recomendation to use OEM website.

Sony website has only 32-bit version of driver which says that it cannot be installed and x64 should be used...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from potentially finding hacked driver (of which I know of none), you are probably at the mercy of Sony who seem to have chosen not to offer 64-bit drivers or support for that machine.

Officially that notebook doesn't even support Windows 7, but [they suggest](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/os7upgrade.pl?mdl=VGNSZ460N):

> However, if one of the drivers that came with the operating system
>   does not work with your system, you can try installing the Windows
>   Vista® version of the driver provided by Sony for your model. Many of
>   the Windows Vista® drivers are compatible with Windows® 7 based on
>   current testing. Make sure you choose the bit version (32-bit or
>   64-bit) that matches your version of Windows® 7.

Unfortunately, since you model officially only supports XP and Vista 32-bit, there are no 64-bit Vista drivers offered to try.

Perhaps check some of Sony's newer, similar models that do officially support 64-bit for drivers that may work.