# Is disabling graphics driver and falling back to CPU for graphics processing a good solution?

Tags: video, drivers, graphics-card, cpu, sony-vaio

I bought a Sony Vaio VGN-FZ50B notebook in Japan about 5 years ago. About a year ago I updated my operating system to windows 7, but I couldn't find a version of drivers for my graphics card for my laptop which would support windows 7. So I searched for drivers for windows 7 for a notebook with the same graphics card as mine and I found one and I installed its drivers. Now for the most time it works correctly, but sometimes when I watch videos it will suddenly send my notebook to the blue screen of death(BSoD).

Recently I have had to watch a lot of videos so I've been BSoDing a lot.

One obvious solution to this problem is to go back to using windows vista and using its drivers. But I don't really want to use vista.

Instead I thought of this hypothetical solution: Since I  am not using graphics intensive applications other than watching online videos, what if I disable graphics card drivers and instead use CPU for graphic processing?
But for this to be possible several things must be true, which are:
1) My CPU must be able to process graphics(perhaps having some kind of internal graphics processing unit)
2) I must know how to disable graphics drivers and switch to CPU for processing.

Unfortunately I don't know any of these. Can you help me?

My graphics card is: NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GT
My CPU is: Intel Core 2 Duo T7100 @1.80GHz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Core 2 Duo family do not have the graphics integrated into the processor ([here's the specs on yours](http://ark.intel.com/products/29759/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7100-%282M-Cache-1_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29)).

Check out [nVidia driver is not installed for x64 Windows 7 (Vaio VGN-SZ460N)](https://superuser.com/questions/356709/nvidia-driver-is-not-installed-for-x64-windows-7-vaio-vgn-sz460n) and [Video drivers for VAIO on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/98394/video-drivers-for-vaio-on-windows-7) (amongst others) to get an idea as to your choices for dealing with newer drivers for "Mobile" graphics when there's no OEM support for the newer version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the graphics card to boot (because the POST will fail without it), but Microsoft has developed a utility they call [Windows Advanced Rasterization Platform (WARP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx) to use the CPU as the graphics engine.

From their documentation:

> WARP allows fast rendering in a variety of situations where hardware implementations are unavailable, including:
>
> > When the user does not have any Direct3D-capable hardware
> >
> > When an application runs as a service or in a server environment
> >
> > When a video card is not installed
> >
> > When a video driver is not available, or is not working correctly
> >
> > When a video card is out of memory, hangs, or would take too many system resources to initialize

Comment: Have you ever used it?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: From what I understood it seems to be a tool for developers to make sure that their applications work when there is no graphic card etc. I have no idea how to use it to make sure that online videos that I watch in firefox go through it.